# Do gods have blood?

Tags: blood, devatas

Do devatas have blood and other things

Do devatas procreate like humans

Devatas have blood,semen,saliva

Comment: Gods do have semen. See the birth story of Agastya (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc241351.html) and there can be many such examples.

Comment: The gods are composed of fine bodies, not material bodies.

Comment: Can you should reference gods have fine bodies

Comment: Gods are made of subtle body or Atman while humans have an earthly gross body sheath over subtle body. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Bodies_Doctrine . A dead person has missing subtle body or Atman. Ofcourse Gods and ghosts(dead spirits) have senses of sight, touch, hear, smell, speak which are actually sensations present in everyone's Atman,not in material body's skull/skeleton which is just a clothing for inferior humans & animals."BG 2.22: As a person sheds worn-out garments and wears new ones, likewise, at the time of death, the soul casts off its worn-out body and enters a new one."